# Take a random user from a Discord server in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to make the bot choose two random users from a Discord server, but every time I did it, the bot choose only her/him and no one else on the server. Here's my code:

```py
@bot.command()

async def random(ctx):
    users = ctx.guild.members
    user1 = choice(users)
    user2 = choice(users)
    await ctx.send(f"{user1} a bolossé {user2}")
```

Comment: Isn't it random.choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you didn't enable `intents.members`.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Remember to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Also to get two random users you can use `random.sample` so you don't get duplicates:

```py
user1, user2 = random.sample(users, 2)
```

#### Reference:

- [How to enable Privileged Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=privileged#privileged-intents)
- [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=sample#random.sample)

Answer (score 0):

Remember to have `intents.members = True` in your code. This allows your bot to access the members of different guilds. Also, be sure to put `intents = discord.Intents.all()` in your code to activate all intents. If you get a console error about this go to [the Discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), go to the Bot section, and go down to where it says Privileged gateway intents and activate those.

So your code should look like this:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "prefix", intents = intents)
intents = discord.intents.all()
intents.members = True
@bot.command()

async def random(ctx):
    users = ctx.guild.members
    user1 = choice(users)
    user2 = choice(users)
    await ctx.send(f"{user1} a bolossé {user2}")
```

Comment: Please debug the code, you'd get an NameError